# Getting a random.choice from a function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm making a 2D Space Invader game using `PyGame`. I made a function to store the `x` and `y` coordinates, the `color` and the `health` of the ship. I used a `random.choice` module to randomly choose the color of the ship, but now I want to grab that color so I can modify the health of a specific ship color.

code snippet of the random modules and the health stuff:

```
if len(enemies) == 0:
    level += 1
    for i in range(wave_length):
        enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100), random.randrange(-1500*level/5, -100), random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"]))
        EnemyColor = Enemy(color)
        if EnemyColor == "red":
            health = 75
        elif EnemyColor == "blue":
            health = 50
        elif EnemyColor == "green":
            health = 25
```

code snippet of the enemy class:

```
class Enemy(Player):
    COLOR_MAP = {
                "red": (RED_SPACE_SHIP, RED_LASER),
                "green": (GREEN_SPACE_SHIP, GREEN_LASER),
                "blue": (BLUE_SPACE_SHIP, BLUE_LASER)
                }

    def __init__(self, x, y, color, health=100):
        super().__init__(x, y, health)
        self.player_img, self.laser_img = self.COLOR_MAP[color]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.player_img)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `color` as a local variable before you instantiate `Enemy`:

```
color = random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"])
enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100), random.randrange(-1500*level/5, -100), color)
```

Then your `if` and `elif` conditions become:

```
if color == "red":
    health = 75
elif color == "blue":
    health = 50
elif color == "green":
    health = 25
```

Aside from the above, note that `EnemyColor = Enemy(color)` does not do what you think it does. Firstly, `Enemy` cannot be instantiated without the other required arguments (`x` and `y`), but `EnemyColor` also does not represent the color of the enemy. It is instead of type `Enemy`.

If you are willing to rethink your design, I would instead set the `health` of `Enemy` within its `__init__` (if you do this, it would be called `self.health`). This would allow you to use the `color` passed in through there.

Your `Enemy` class would look like this:

```
class Enemy(Player):
    COLOR_MAP = {
                "red": (RED_SPACE_SHIP, RED_LASER),
                "green": (GREEN_SPACE_SHIP, GREEN_LASER),
                "blue": (BLUE_SPACE_SHIP, BLUE_LASER)
                }

    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        if color == "red":
            health = 75
        elif color == "blue":
            health = 50
        elif color == "green":
            health = 25

        super().__init__(x, y, health)
        self.player_img, self.laser_img = self.COLOR_MAP[color]
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.player_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define function to retrieve color from an instantiated enemy object as follows.

```
def color(enemy):
  return next(k for k, v in Enemy.COLOR_MAP.items() if (v==(enemy.player_img, enemy.laser_img)))
```

**Explanation**

Iterates over Enemy class COLOR_MAP until it finds the matching player_img and laser_img

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main mistakes:

1. By doing `EnemyColor = Enemy(color)` you are not getting the `enemy`'s color, you are trying to create a new `Enemy` instance (in an invalid way). Instead you can simply do `enemy.color`. This is the way to access an instance's attribute.
2. You are simply defining a local variable called `health`. If you want to modify the new `Enemy` instance's attribute, you should instead write: `enemy.health = ...`

---

But I think it would be a lot easier to define a mapping between color and matching health and avoid the `if/else`. So you can create:

```py
color_to_health = {"red": 75,
                   "blue": 50,
                   "green": 25}
```

And then all you need to do is save the `color` beforehand and choose the matching `health` directly to the constructor:

```py
x = random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100)
y = random.randrange(-1500*level/5, -100)

color = random.choice(["red", "blue", "green"]
health = color_to_health.get(color, 100)

enemy = Enemy(x, y, color, health )
```

Using [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) allows for a default value of `100` if no matching color was selected.